# Calculating Isoelectric point from a multifasta file

Tags: fasta, proteins

I need to calculate Isoelectric point from a multifasta file, is there any python code or web tool that allows me to do that?

Comment: Can you use Python (biopython has a very straightforward method for pI calculations, `Bio.SeqUtils.IsoelectricPoint`)?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [EMBOSS Pepstats](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/Tools/seqstats/emboss_pepstats/) for this. It takes a multi-fasta as input and produces a table that contains various statistics related to the protein, including isoelectric point.